# Convert Row to Column mySQL with ID (not pivoting)

Tags: mysql, row, multiple-columns

I have a value store in a database like this:

```
ID     |   Date    |   Value
----------------------------------------------
1      |   11/20   |   1
1      |   11/21   |   2
2      |   11/20   |   10 
2      |   11/21   |   20
```

However, I need it to be like this:

```
 Date  | Value ID 1    |   Value ID 2
----------------------------------------------
  11/20|  1            |   10
  11/21|  2            |   20
```

So the new column can be plot in a trend (column 1 = date, column 2 = value#1, column 3 = value #2, column 4 = value#4, etc).

---

Here is the query for a single tag:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ID, _date, ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.Val,  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY
JOIN (SELECT @curRow:=0) i
INNER JOIN ESYNC_TAGS ON ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.TAGID=ESYNC_TAGS.ID
WHERE ESYNC_TAGS.NAME='I_TT_21052'  AND ESYNC_TAGS.STATIONID=1 AND (_date BETWEEN now()-INTERVAL 45 MINUTE AND now()) ) s
WHERE row_number mod 60 = 0;
```

And the results:

```
 ID  | Date  | Value ID 1   |   Row
----------------------------------------------
  1  |  11/20|  1           |   1
  1  |  11/21|  2           |   2
```

EDIT :

With some modification my query look like this

```
SELECT *
            FROM (
            SELECT ID,  _date, ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.Val,  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number,
            if (ESYNC_TAGS.NAME='I_TT_21052', ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.Val, NULL) as 'I_TT_21052',
            if (ESYNC_TAGS.NAME='I_TT_91214', ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.Val, NULL) as 'I_TT_40011'
            FROM ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY
            JOIN (SELECT @curRow:=0) i
            INNER JOIN ESYNC_TAGS ON ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.TAGID=ESYNC_TAGS.ID
            WHERE ESYNC_TAGS.STATIONID=1 AND (_date BETWEEN now()-INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND now()) ) s
            WHERE row_number mod 1 = 0
            ORDER BY ID ,_date;
```

Result look like this

[SQL RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDawF.png)

My Problem now is to move the data from the last column at the same place as the other (get the value line up with the date)

EDIT #2 : Finally for further reference query look like this :

```
SELECT _date, I_TT_21052, I_TT_40011, row_number
            From(
            SELECT max(_date) as _date, max(I_TT_21052) as I_TT_21052, max(I_TT_40011) as I_TT_40011, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number

                                FROM (
                                SELECT ID,  _date, ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.Val,
                                if (ESYNC_TAGS.NAME='I_TT_21052', ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.Val, NULL) as 'I_TT_21052',
                                if (ESYNC_TAGS.NAME='I_TT_91214', ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.Val, NULL) as 'I_TT_40011'
                                FROM ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY
                                JOIN (SELECT @curRow:=0) i
                                INNER JOIN ESYNC_TAGS ON ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.TAGID=ESYNC_TAGS.ID
                                WHERE ESYNC_TAGS.STATIONID=1 AND (_date BETWEEN now()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND now()) ) s

            GROUP BY _date)v
            WHERE row_number mod 150 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
case when id=1 then count(Id) else 0 end) as Value1,
case when id=2 then count(Id) else 0 end) as Value2
from ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY
```

This is not exact but try this kind of query you will get result